# How to set the app icon using electron-forge package on Mac?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Can somebody please tell me the instructions for using a custom icon, when compiling an electron app (on mac) when using `electron-forge package`? Using `--icon` gives me an error:

```
error: unknown option `--icon'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Figured it out. Configure the path to your icon in your `package.json`.

Electron-Forge v5:

```
{
  ...
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      ...
      "electronPackagerConfig": {
        "icon": "path/to/icon.icns"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Electron-Forge v6:

```
{
  ...
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      ...
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "path/to/icon.icns"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Might be obvious to others, but this doesn't change the icon when running in `electron-forge start`

Comment: I can't find the documentation for this anywhere- can someone point to some (hopefully always-current) documentation link? (the larger question is: what are the parameters/constraints of this icon? etc...)

Comment: @Phildo https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#packager-config although it is now documenting Version 6.

Comment: Hi all. I've updated my answer to show instructions for both v5 and v6.

Comment: Is this solution cross-platform? It seems macOS specific? Since `package.json` is shared by all platforms. I wonder how this could extend to Windows.

Comment: Apparently, the electron app do not accept .icns. they only accept .ico icons.

Comment: @TengBangWei windows icons use `.ico` and macOS uses `.icns`

Comment: Just remove the extension from the "icon" property as pointed out by @cris answer. And make sure you do have the proper files in place, e.g. icon.icns, icon.ico and icon.png.

Comment: Is this a relative path to the config file?

Comment: @LMS5400 yeah, that's what I have: https://github.com/will-stone/browserosaurus/blob/49cbd6409e0eeaa6754c93bfdd5387efe027d0c0/forge.config.ts#L15

Comment: @WillStone, thanks, ya, it ended up working for me after a reboot. Looks like windows held the old icons around.

Answer (score 8):

Per [the `Options.icon` documentation](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#icon):

> If the file extension is omitted, it is auto-completed to the correct extension based on the platform, including when platform: 'all' is in effect

Given that, set the value without extension:

```json
"icon": "./assets/icon"
```

This is confirmed to work on both Windows and Mac.